# what about DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system

I want to know all about DNS

Comment: You probably are better off by buying a book or finding some tutorials online, then come back here for additional info.

Comment: I want to know all about unicorns

Comment: read http://www.oreillymaker.com/link/31658/unicorns/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to know everything about DNS then make [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0026OR2QS) your new Bible.

Comment: No need for tiny URLs, especially if they have Amazon affiliate codes in them. But yours didn't, did it?

Comment: and is that super bad?.. if so then why? i'm not selling anything, so my opinion is not based on a financial benefit, I just merely provide a link to a book, which just happens to be about dns. i also haven't seen any regulations with regards to the links, but if I missed the T&C pls point me to the right direction...

Answer (score 4):

Not one to immediately jump to Wikipedia, I do think [the entry on DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) is a good starter.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [DNS Resource Directory](http://www.dns.net/dnsrd/).